# WCHAR not functioning properly in linux

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wchar-t, widechar

I am trying to use wstring in a C++ program which is as follows:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const wstring NAME = L"STACKOVERFLOW";
int main()
{
    wcout<<NAME;
}
```

Now, In windows, the output is printing as `STACKOVERFLOW`. But while compiling it with wsl(linux), I am getting output as `?????r????????????????` . Why is this so?

Comment: What do you see if you do `./a.out | xxd -g 1`?

Comment: WSL supports UTF-8.  WCHAR on Linux is UTF-32.

Comment: @Eljay `00000000: 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 57 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ??????W?????????
00000010: 3f 64 3f 2c 16 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ?d?,.???????????
00000020: 3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ?...............
00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000040: 00 00`

Comment: @RichardCritten So what to do now to make it work properly?

Comment: Change `wstring` to `string`, change `L"STACKOVERFLOW"` to `"STACKOVERFLOW"`, and change `wcout` to `cout`.

Comment: @Eljay Yeah that is a good approach but I have tried to give minimum reproducible code here. Currently, I am using wstring in a large project and if i try to change the whole code, that will be a big mess. So, is there any other way to approach this?

Comment: You might be able to write your own `wcout` which converts to UTF-8 and outputs to `cout` behind the scenes.  That could be a near drop-in replacement for the existing code on a big project.  I've no idea as to the implementation details, I'd have to read up on I/O streams — which is a deep subject, because of locales, facets, conversions.  Maybe such change could be injected up into the real `std::wcout` at the start of `main`.

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @C.M. that won't work for a huge legacy project. No one is gonna convert everything in it to UTF-8. You have to use UTF-16 in older Windows. Only newer Windows have UTF-8 locale support